# Accessing Endpoint from ExceptionMapper in Jersey

Tags: jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm puzzled on how would I be able to fetch the current request handler (org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.process.Endpoint) in an ExceptionMapper... Take a look at following code...

```
public class ValidationExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ValidationException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ValidationException exception) {
        // Here I would like to know which endpoint triggered this exception... 
    }
}
```

Handling of the exceptions would be based on what kind of annotations were present on the input data that failed validations.

Jersey's Endpoint seems to have all the information that I might need. I would prefer to use any option that JAX-RS conforms to. But at this point, I'm ready to look for any alternatives.

**Note**: I did look at ConstraintViolation.getRootBean()... It points out at the resource rather than at the method that gets invoked... I'm interested in fetching the endpoint rather than just the resource.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you only need the method, you can inject `ResourceInfo`. You might also want to check what the actual concrete class type is. You may be able to cast it and get even more information. If it's a `RoutingContext` (which it just _may be_), [that contract gives you access to the `Endpoint`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/927b4d0605aeb119d15e9623dab65c8aec2c8e20/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/internal/routing/RoutingContext.java#L134)

Comment: You can also inject [`ExtendedUriInfo`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/927b4d0605aeb119d15e9623dab65c8aec2c8e20/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ExtendedUriInfo.java), which has a lot of information also.

Comment: Out of these options, `ResourceInfo` is the only standard JAX-RS API. All you can really get from that is the (reflection) `Method`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your quick response!